# encircle the object depending on the set percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, loader

I have such task: a circle without borders and we get some percentages (from user or just enter by ourself - doesn't mater), after it the border of circle should be filled depending on this number. 
I'm trying to use SVG. But it's not clear for me. It doesn't work with persentages and I don't know how to get right number for all length

```html
<svg width="270" height="270">
  
    <circle 
            r="115" cx="135" cy="135"
            fill="none";
            stroke="blue"
            stroke-width="15"            
            stroke-dasharray="1000"
            stroke-dashoffset="0%">
    <animate 
            attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
            attributeType="CSS"
            from="1000" to="00"
            begin="0s" dur="2s"/>

</svg>
```

[Image to see how it shoul be](http://blob:https://web.telegram.org/39f18c0f-e3f4-433f-b1fa-d580dfbcc472)

Comment: I didn't get your question. You mean to say your circle will be first rendered on browser without border. then you will pass some value which will be an input to the circle's border which will animate ?

Is this you want ?\

Comment: @Krishna9960 Yes, for example, if we enter 50, we will see a half of the circle, 100 - full circle.

Answer (score 0):

One observation : the value of `stroke-dasharray` if you want it to be full should be the circumference of the circle in pixels. So `2*Pi*r`.

The stroke-dashoffset is the amount of pixels that are offset from the stroke, so for example :

A circle of 115px radius will have a circumference of `2*Pi*115=722.56` 723px.
If we want to fill it at 75%, we must offset the stroke by `723*(1-0.75)=180.75` 181px.

Examples below :

```html
<svg id="svg" width="270" height="270">
    <circle id="circle"
            r="115" cx="135" cy="135"
            fill="none";
            stroke="blue"
            stroke-dasharray="723"
            stroke-dashoffset="361"
            stroke-width="15">
        <animate id="animation" 
        attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  
        attributeType="CSS" 
        begin="0s" 
        to="361"
        from="723"
        dur="2s"/>
  </circle>
            
            <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">50%</text>
</svg>

<svg id="svg" width="270" height="270">
    <circle id="circle"
            r="115" cx="135" cy="135"
            fill="none";
            stroke="blue"
            stroke-dasharray="723"
            stroke-dashoffset="181"
            stroke-width="15">
        <animate id="animation" 
        attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  
        attributeType="CSS" 
        begin="0s" 
        to="181"
        from="723"
        dur="2s"/>
  </circle>
            
            <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">75%</text>
</svg>
```